# Concerned with query size using non-unique join conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a situation at work. I work in housing. We raise *orders* to houses (so our contractors can go out and repair the houses).

Orders contain one or more *jobs*. A *dwelling* has zero, one or more orders raised against it.

This is a brief data definition. I've simplified the tables - but hopefully you get the idea. An order can contain many jobs, and a property can have many orders.

```
CREATE TABLE dwellings (
id VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE orders (
id VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
created_by VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
created_on DATE NOT NULL,
dwelling_id VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES dwellings(id)
);

CREATE TABLE jobs (
id VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
sor_id VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
order_id VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL REFERENCES orders(id)
);
```

And populated:

```
INSERT INTO dwellings VALUES ('00ABC', '2 The Mews House Little Boston London E1 1EE');
INSERT INTO dwellings VALUES ('5H88H', '3 Electric House Snodsbury S1 1IT');

INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('000001-A', 'CSMITH', DATE '2016-03-10', '00ABC');
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('000002-A', 'CSMITH', DATE '2016-03-11', '00ABC');
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('000003-A', 'AJONES', DATE '2016-03-16', '00ABC');
INSERT INTO orders VALUES ('000004-A', 'CSMITH', DATE '2016-03-16', '5H88H');

INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('001', '000AA0', '000001-A');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('002', '123BB0', '000001-A');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('003', '000AA0', '000002-A');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('004', '787XD7', '000003-A');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('005', '000AA0', '000003-A');
INSERT INTO jobs VALUES ('006', '787XD7', '000004-A');
```

An analyst wants to know agents who are raising orders that are similar to previous orders. The thing under scrutiny is the SOR_ID, which denotes the type of job. Remember, there is one or more job associated with each order. So the task is: **produce a report showing orders that contain one or more duplicate job types to previous orders at the property**.

The report I'm building will have these column headings.

- Agent Name
- Order Id
- Address
- Previous Order Id
- Duplicate Job Types

Here is the start of a query that gets there. I haven't executed it against the database because there are 50,000 properties and 100,000 orders and 200,000 jobs. I'm concerned about the size of the table because I'm joining on columns that are not unique.

```
select * from orders ord 
join orders ord2 on ord.dwelling_id = ord2.dwelling_id --shaky
    and ord.id <> ord2.id
    and ord.created_on - ord2.created_on between 0 and 90
join jobs job on job.order_id = ord.id
join jobs job2 on job2.order_id = ord2.id
where job.sor_id = job2.sor_id
```

I'm looking for recommendations for how you might refactor this query into something more manageable (without PLSQL). Note that I haven't used LAG / LEAD and I haven't yet used LISTAGG to collapse the job type codes. That will come later. I'm concerned about how expensive the query is at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned. Oracle 11g or maybe 12 something by now.

Comment: Consider to add the [oracle] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**:

```
SELECT o.created_by AS agent_name,
       d.address,
       LISTAGG( o.id, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY o.created_on ) AS order_ids,
       j.sor_id AS job_type
FROM   dwellings d
       INNER JOIN orders o
       ON ( o.dwelling_id = d.id )
       INNER JOIN jobs j
       ON ( j.order_id = o.id )
GROUP BY o.created_by, d.address, j.sor_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

**Output**:

```
AGENT_NAME ADDRESS                                      ORDER_IDS         JOB_TYPE 
---------- -------------------------------------------- ----------------- ----------
CSMITH     2 The Mews House Little Boston London E1 1EE 000001-A,000002-A 000AA0
```

Lists the jobs with the different order ids that were of the same type and placed by the same agent at the same address. The orders are listed in chronological order within the comma-separated list.

However, if you want it with your headings then you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT o.created_by AS agent_name,
         o.id,
         d.address,
         LAG( o.id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY o.created_by, d.address, j.sor_id
                            ORDER BY o.created_on
                          ) AS previous_order_id,
         j.sor_id AS job_type
  FROM   dwellings d
         INNER JOIN orders o
         ON ( o.dwelling_id = d.id )
         INNER JOIN jobs j
         ON ( j.order_id = o.id )
)
WHERE  previous_order_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Which would output:

```
AGENT_NAME ID         ADDRESS                                      PREVIOUS_ORDER_ID JOB_TYPE 
---------- ---------- -------------------------------------------- ----------------- ----------
CSMITH     000002-A   2 The Mews House Little Boston London E1 1EE 000001-A          000AA0
```

If you want to consider multiple agents then you can remove `o.created_by` from the `GROUP BY`or `PARTITION BY` clauses. For the top query you would then need to use `LISTAGG` to get all the agents. Like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( o.created_by, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY o.created_on ) AS agent_name,
       d.address,
       LISTAGG( o.id, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY o.created_on ) AS order_ids,
       j.sor_id AS job_type
FROM   dwellings d
       INNER JOIN orders o
       ON ( o.dwelling_id = d.id )
       INNER JOIN jobs j
       ON ( j.order_id = o.id )
GROUP BY d.address, j.sor_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Or, for the second query, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT o.created_by AS agent_name,
         o.id,
         d.address,
         LAG( o.id ) OVER ( PARTITION BY d.address, j.sor_id
                            ORDER BY o.created_on
                          ) AS previous_order_id,
         j.sor_id AS job_type
  FROM   dwellings d
         INNER JOIN orders o
         ON ( o.dwelling_id = d.id )
         INNER JOIN jobs j
         ON ( j.order_id = o.id )
)
WHERE  previous_order_id IS NOT NULL;
```

Both the queries would then also output the order with id `000003-A` placed by `AJONES`.

Comment: The same agent would probably not insert duplicates. But different agents might.

Answer (score 1):

Changes i would try out:

- `ord.id <> ord2.id` : `ord2.id < ord.id` (not sure if that's applicable for you)
- `ord.created_on - ord2.created_on between 0 and 90` : `ord2.created_on <= ord.created_on and ord2.created_on >= ord.created_on - 90` (not sure if the RDBMS can do that optimization)
- Move `job.sor_id = job2.sor_id` into the ON clause (But the RDBMS will probably do that for you)

```sql
select * from orders ord 
join orders ord2 
    on  ord2.dwelling_id = ord.dwelling_id
    and ord2.id < ord.id
    and ord2.created_on <= ord.created_on        
    and ord2.created_on >= ord.created_on - 90
join jobs job on job.order_id = ord.id
join jobs job2 
    on  job2.order_id = ord2.id
    and job2.sor_id   = job.sor_id;
```

Indexes you will need:

- orders(dwelling_id, created_on, id)
- jobs(order_id, sor_id)